# In swagger 2.0 (openapi), how to have a different resource definition between POST and PUT request?

Tags: api, inheritance, swagger, openapi

If we look at a message API (for example)
I want it to be able to

- create a message
- get a message
- update a message

A message contains an external reference (a unique id from the consumer)

- This external_id should be set at creation with a POST request
- This external_id, could not be changed with a PATCH

What is the solution to implement it?

An API sample:

```
swagger: '2.0'

host: api.com
basePath: /v2
schemes:
  - https

info:
  title: dummy
  version: 1.0.0

consumes:
  - application/json

produces:
  - application/json


paths:
  /messages:
    post:
      summary: Create a message
      parameters:
        - name: message
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'

      responses:

        201:
          description: Ok
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'


  /messages/{id}:
    get:

      summary: "Get a message by ID"
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: The message ID
          required: true
          type: string
          format: uuid

      responses:

        200:
          description: OK - the message
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'

    patch:
      summary: Modify a message
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: The message ID
          required: true
          type: string
          format: uuid

        - name: message
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'

      responses:

        201:
          description: Ok
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'

definitions:

  Message:
    type: object
    required:
      - id
      - external_id
      - title
      - content
      - created_at

    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        readOnly: true

      external_id:
        type: string
        description: "Your own reference ID"

      title:
        type: string

      content:
        type: string

      created_at:
        type: string
        format: date-time
        readOnly: true
```

The only solutions I see:

- defining 2 definitions (Message and UpdatedMessage) using allOf
- not using the definition in the PATCH method or in the GET/POST method

Is there a better solution to achieve this? The ideal solution would be to have only one Message definition, and in the PATCH method, to override the Message definition (removing the field).

I don't know if it is possible.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this use case, you must define 2 messages:

- An `UpdateMessage` containing all properties except `external_id`
- A `Message` containing all `UpdateMessage` properties plus `external_id` using `allOf` is the only way of achieving this with OpenAPI (fka. Swagger) 2.0 version.

Here's the corresponding YAML:

```
swagger: '2.0'

host: api.com
basePath: /v2
schemes:
  - https

info:
  title: dummy
  version: 1.0.0

consumes:
  - application/json

produces:
  - application/json


paths:
  /messages:
    post:
      summary: Create a message
      parameters:
        - name: message
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'

      responses:

        201:
          description: Ok
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'


  /messages/{id}:
    get:

      summary: "Get a message by ID"
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: The message ID
          required: true
          type: string
          format: uuid

      responses:

        200:
          description: OK - the message
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'

    patch:
      summary: Modify a message
      parameters:
        - name: id
          in: path
          description: The message ID
          required: true
          type: string
          format: uuid

        - name: message
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateMessage'

      responses:

        201:
          description: Ok
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Message'

definitions:

  UpdateMessage:
    type: object
    required:
      - id
      - title
      - content
      - created_at

    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        readOnly: true

      title:
        type: string

      content:
        type: string

      created_at:
        type: string
        format: date-time
        readOnly: true

  Message:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/UpdateMessage'
      - required:
          - external_id
        properties:
          external_id:
            type: string
            description: "Your own reference ID"
```